# Algorithm to control acceleration until a position is reached

Tags: algorithm, math, physics

I have a point that moves (in one dimension), and I need it to move smoothly. So I think that it's velocity has to be a continuous function and I need to control the acceleration and then calculate it's velocity and position.

The algorithm doesn't seem something obvious to me, but I guess this must be a common problem, I just can't find the solution.

**Notes:**

- The final destination of the object may change while it's moving and the movement needs to be smooth anyway.
- I guess that a naive implementation would produce bouncing, and I need to avoid that.

Comment: Might want to check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a perfect candidate for using a "critically damped spring".

Conceptually you attach the point to the target point with a spring, or piece of elastic.  The spring is damped so that you get no 'bouncing'.  You can control how fast the system reacts by changing a constant called the "SpringConstant".  This is essentially how strong the piece of elastic is.

Basically you apply two forces to the position, then integrate this over time.  The first force is that applied by the spring, Fs = SpringConstant * DistanceToTarget.  The second is the damping force, Fd = -CurrentVelocity * 2 * sqrt( SpringConstant ).

The CurrentVelocity forms part of the state of the system, and can be initialised to zero.

In each step, you multiply the sum of these two forces by the time step.  This gives you the change of the value of the CurrentVelocity.  Multiply this by the time step again and it will give you the displacement.

We add this to the actual position of the point.

In C++ code:

```
float CriticallyDampedSpring( float a_Target,
                              float a_Current,
                              float & a_Velocity,
                              float a_TimeStep )
{
    float currentToTarget = a_Target - a_Current;
    float springForce = currentToTarget * SPRING_CONSTANT;
    float dampingForce = -a_Velocity * 2 * sqrt( SPRING_CONSTANT );
    float force = springForce + dampingForce;
    a_Velocity += force * a_TimeStep;
    float displacement = a_Velocity * a_TimeStep;
    return a_Current + displacement;
}
```

In systems I was working with a value of around 5 was a good point to start experimenting with the value of the spring constant.  Set it too high will result in too fast a reaction, and too low the point will react too slowly.

Note, you might be best to make a class that keeps the velocity state rather than have to pass it into the function over and over.

I hope this is helpful, good luck :)

**EDIT:** In case it's useful for others, it's easy to apply this to 2 or 3 dimensions.  In this case you can just apply the CriticallyDampedSpring independently once for each dimension.  Depending on the motion you want you might find it better to work in polar coordinates (for 2D), or spherical coordinates (for 3D).

Comment: +1 for the explanation and the formula. (And it was a problem I was pondering some time ago)

Comment: Looks interesting, tomorrow I'll test the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alex, I've already accepted the answer, but I'm thinking: is there any way to make the velocity function to be symmetric? So it would accelerate as fast as it de-accelerates? Right now it´s very fast at the beginning and slow at the end.

Comment: Off the top of my head it doesn't sound right that it should be significantly faster at the start.  Do you initialize the velocity to zero?

Comment: (I was going to post something earlier, but hesitated.) When I read this answer, I was very close to "-1"-ing it, because even though it's well thought out, this is not appropriate for trajectory planning.

Comment: *I'm maybe a bit late to the party*, but the `2` isn't that the mass?

Comment: For me, this also worked for following an object (instead of just reaching a position). To do this, I only had to pass relative velocity (current object velocity - target object velocity) instead of just current object velocity.

Comment: I tried to implement this in 2D using javascript to follow the mouse cursor. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/3170/
But it doesn't seem to be working entirely well, sometimes the object gets farther instead of closer, and kind of diagonally. Maybe there's some error in my code.

Comment: @brunodeleo the problem with your code is that you are not tracking the velocity for each dimension separately. That is, you need a velocityX and a velocityY.

Comment: Excelent! Thanks @AlexDeem :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear exactly what you're after, but I'm going to assume the following:

1. There is some maximum acceleration;
2. You want the object to have stopped moving when it reaches the destination;
3. Unlike velocity, you do not require acceleration to be continuous.

Let *A* be the maximum acceleration (by which I mean the acceleration is always between -*A* and *A*).

The equation you want is

```
v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2 a d
```

where *v_f* = 0 is the final velocity, *v_i* is the initial (current) velocity, and *d* is the distance to the destination (when you switch from acceleration *A* to acceleration -*A* -- that is, from speeding up to slowing down; here I'm assuming *d* is positive).

Solving:

```
d = v_i^2 / (2A)
```

is the distance. (The negatives cancel).

If the current distance remaining is greater than *d*, speed up as quickly as possible. Otherwise, begin slowing down.

Let's say you update the object's position every *t_step* seconds. Then:

```
new_position = old_position + old_velocity * t_step + (1/2)a(t_step)^2
new_velocity = old_velocity + a * t_step.
```

If the destination is between *new_position* and *old_position* (i.e., the object reached its destination in between updates), simply set *new_position* = *destination*.

Comment: @Damain A is a constant that you can set to whatever. Higher values of A mean the object (de-)accelerates more quickly. You will have to experiment to determine what value for A results in the behavior you want. The algorithm described above tells you when to set a = A or a = -A, where "a" is the object's acceleration. I have updated my answer to explain how to compute position from this. Also, this will result in the symmetric speedup/slowdown you requested in another post.

Comment: The problem with just setting `new_position = destination` at the end is it can cause a spike in acceleration at the last point that may exceed the maximum acceleration (it basically _slams_ into the final position; the velocity is low, but the deceleration can be quite high because of the discontinuous velocity from the previous calculation).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like Alex Deem's answer for trajectory planning, but with limits on force and velocity:

In pseudocode:

```
xtarget:  target position
vtarget:  target velocity*
x: object position
v: object velocity
dt: timestep

F = Ki * (xtarget-x) + Kp * (vtarget-v);
F = clipMagnitude(F, Fmax);
v = v + F * dt;
v = clipMagnitude(v, vmax);
x = x + v * dt;

clipMagnitude(y, ymax):
   r = magnitude(y) / ymax
   if (r <= 1)
       return y;
   else
       return y * (1/r);
```

where Ki and Kp are tuning constants, Fmax and vmax are maximum force and velocity. This should work for 1-D, 2-D, or 3-D situations (magnitude(y) = abs(y) in 1-D, otherwise use vector magnitude).

Answer (score -2):

You need an easing formula, which you would call at a set interval, passing in the time elapsed, start point, end point and duration you want the animation to be.

Doing time-based calculations will account for slow clients and other random hiccups. Since it calculates on time elapsed vs. the time in which it has to compkete, it will account for slow intervals between calls when returning how far along your point should be in the animation.

The jquery.easing plugin has a ton of easing functions you can look at:

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

I've found it best to pass in 0 and 1 as my start and end point, since it will return a floating point between the two, you can easily apply it to the real value you are modifying using multiplication.

Comment: An easing formula will not work for me because the destination point can change at any time. With an easing formula I would have to change the start/end point at that moment and the movement won't be smooth then.