# In an array, how do I find the closest key given a float value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm making an "acceleration" array like this:

```
acc["0100"] = 1;
acc["0300"] = 2;
acc["0600"] = 4;
acc["0900"] = 8;
acc["2000"] = 16;
acc["5000"] = 32;
```

And, when the user presses a key, I start a timer: `this._startTick = (new Date()).getTime();`

Now I have a timer that checks if the key is still pressed. If so, then I do something like:

```
this._delay = (new Date()).getTime() - this._startTick;
```

And now, based on `this._delay`, I'd like to find one of the previous values (1, 2, 4 or 8). How would you do that?

NB: if the value is greater than "`5.0`" then the result should always be `32`.

NOTA: my goal is, given an elapsed time, find out which value is the best. I started the way I've just explained, but if you have another solution, I'll take it!

Comment: You're not using `acc` as an _Array_, but as an _Object_ (which works in _JavaScript_ because _Arrays_ inherit from _Object_).

Comment: @PaulS. Ok my bad. So maybe you have another way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to operate on an array than on an object:

```
var accArr = [];
for (time in acc) {
    accArr.push({time: time, value: acc[time]});
}
```

Assuming you have an array, you can do:

```
function getValue(delay) {
    var diffs = accArr.map(function (e) { return Math.abs(e.time - delay); });
    return accArr[diffs.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, diffs))].value;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Well, you didn't mention that this is a performance-critical function. In that case, I would recommend picking a granularity (e.g. `0.05`, so the multiplier for delay is `20`) and pre-calculating all values from `0` to `MAX_DELAY`:

```
var multiplier = 20,
    granularity = 1 / multiplier;

var delayValues = (function () {
    var result = [];
    for (var delay = 0; delay <= MAX_DELAY; delay += granularity) {
        result.push(getValue(delay));
    }
    return result;
})();
```

During the animation, fetching the value will be a simple lookup in a relatively small table:

```
function getValueFast(delay) {
    return (delayValues[Math.round(delay * multiplier)] || 
            delayValues[delayValues.length - 1])
}
```

[JSPerf comparison](http://jsperf.com/get-value-delay) between this solution and simple `if` statements shows they perform equally fast for searching around a middle value.

Comment: Easier or faster in term of execution time?

Comment: Easier as in "more convenient", because arrays have utility functions that objects don't: `map`, `indexOf`, etc. With 5 items in a list/object, don't bother with execution time optimization.

Comment: If I have 100 sprites and I have to recalculate acceleration each 1/60 s this means 60 * 100 * 5 = 30000 comparisons / seconds, instead of "Aadit M Shah" #1 suggestion (which would be a mean of 15000 comparisons / seconds). I think this is a "basic" optimization that I should take care of. I don't know if I'm wrong...

Comment: And 100 sprites in a game is few (count numbers for scoring, bubbles, hints, explosions, not to talk about collision detection between each "real" sprite (there's no collision to do with the previous ones)).

Comment: OK, added a version optimized for speed and not for elegance :)

Comment: So your last code implies that (1) the timer will never exceed the `MAX_DELAY` value and (2) the 'tick' of the timer should be a multiple of `0.05`?

Comment: I've updated your code to reflect something closer to what you did: http://jsperf.com/get-value-delay/2 And it's faster **`;-)`**

Comment: The timer can exceed `MAX_DELAY`, it's just there to limit the creation of `delayValues`. If the actual delay is greater, then the second part of `||` from getValueFast is used and the value of the last element of the array is returned.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XAmkM/1/) is the jsfiddle test page.

```
var getAccForDelay = (function () {
    var acc = {
        0.1: 1,
        0.3: 2,
        0.6: 4,
        0.9: 8,
        2.0: 16,
        5.0: 32
    };

    return function(delay) {
        var key,
            bestKey = undefined,
            absDiff, 
            absDiffMin = Number.MAX_VALUE;

        for (key in acc) {
            if (acc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                absDiff = Math.abs(delay - key);
                if (absDiffMin > absDiff) {
                    absDiffMin = absDiff;
                    bestKey = key;
                }
            }
        } 
        return bestKey === undefined ? undefined : acc[bestKey];
    };
}());
```

Test:

```
console.clear();
console.log(getAccForDelay(0));
console.log(getAccForDelay(0.33));
console.log(getAccForDelay(3.14));
console.log(getAccForDelay(123456.789));
```

Output:

```
1
2
16
32
```

**=== UPDATE ===**

The above solution doesn't utilize of the fact that `acc` is sorted by key. I optimized the code by replacing linear search with [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which is much faster on long arrays. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/XAmkM/3/) is the test page.

```
var getAccForDelay = (function () {
    var accKey   = [ 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 2.0, 5.0 ],
        accValue = [   1,   2,   4,   8,  16,  32 ],
        accLength = accKey.length;

    return function(delay) {
        var iLeft, iMiddle, iRight;

        iLeft = 0;
        if (delay <= accKey[iLeft])
            return accValue[iLeft];
        iRight = accLength - 1;
        if (accKey[iRight] <= delay)
            return accValue[iRight];        
        while (true) {
            if (iRight - iLeft === 1)
                return delay - accKey[iLeft] < accKey[iRight] - delay ? accValue[iLeft] : accValue[iRight];
            iMiddle = ~~((iLeft + iRight) / 2);
            if (delay < accKey[iMiddle])
                iRight = iMiddle;
            else if (accKey[iMiddle] < delay)
                iLeft = iMiddle;
            else
                return accValue[iMiddle];
        }
    };
}());
```

Comment: If `delay == 12345.456`, the value should be 8. How would you do?

Comment: @OlivierPons Your updated acc object made the problem harder, so I had to completely rewrite my answer.

Comment: I don't understant the part "`if (acc.hasOwnProperty(key))`" because it's in a `for()` and `acc` will always have the property `key`... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @OlivierPons I iterate over the properties of acc, and this hasOwnProperty check ensures that I won't accidentally use an inherited property. This is not needed in this particular case, but this is the "standard way" to iterate over an objects own properties, so I wrote the code this way.

Comment: This is a very nice answer, I think I'll check it as good, even though, I'm hitting another big problem: slowing down. I think I'll implement something like here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20905/simple-speed-deceleration-with-variable-time-step or maybe from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100811/algorithm-to-control-acceleration-until-a-position-is-reached

Comment: @OlivierPons Have you verified that the above solution is slow? Or what do you think is behind the slowness?

Comment: The `for (key in acc) {}` implies that for each re-calculation there a *full* loop on the *whole* array. Aadit M Shah's answer #1 code means there's a mean of 50% loop on the array. Not more. I mean... I'm looking for something that could return as soon as possible the answer.

Comment: @OlivierPons I've optimized the code, pls. check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea. I've tried to add your code here http://jsperf.com/get-value-delay/2 . The optimization of `getValueFast()` seems to be the fastest one...

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion I think the best solution to this problem is to write a function which picks the best acceleration based on the time using `if` statements as follows:

```
function getAcceleration(time) {
    if (time < 0.20) return 1;
    if (time < 0.45) return 2;
    if (time < 0.75) return 4;
    if (time < 1.45) return 8;
    if (time < 3.50) return 16;
    return 32;
}
```

However this is a static solution. If that's alright with you then I recommend you use this method. On the other hand if you need a dynamic solution then use this instead:

```
var getAcceleration = createAccelerationMap(0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 2.0, 5.0);

function createAccelerationMap(previous) {
    var length = arguments.length, limits = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < length;) {
        var current = arguments[i++];
        limits.push((previous + current) / 2);
        previous = current;
    }

    return function (time) {
        var length = limits.length, acceleration = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < length;) {
            if (time < limits[i++]) return acceleration;
            acceleration *= 2;
        }

        return acceleration;
    };
}
```

Either way you may then use `getAcceleration` as follows:

```
console.log(getAcceleration(0));          // 1
console.log(getAcceleration(0.33));       // 2
console.log(getAcceleration(0.64));       // 4
console.log(getAcceleration(1.42));       // 8
console.log(getAcceleration(3.14));       // 16
console.log(getAcceleration(123456.789)); // 32
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QepT7/

Answer (score 0):

If the `0.1` is the number of seconds, and you want to round to 1 decimal you can do something this:

```
// 0.42332 * 10 = 4.2332 
// Math.round( ) will be 4
// 4 / 10 = 0.4
acc[ (Math.round(this._delay * 10) / 10).toString() ]
```

Comment: But the almost all the indications are between 0 - 1. How would you handle that case?

Comment: And if there's no corresponding key? My question was not precise enough, I'll modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var seconds = this._delay.toString().substring(0,2)

console.log(acc[seconds]);
```

This is a straight-forward approach of your problem: First I convert the float to a string, second I cut off everything after the third character.

Comment: It is straight forward but what if the delay is over 100?

Answer (score 0):

What units are you using?

```
this._startTick = (new Date()).getTime();
//       ms     =                 ms

this._delay = (new Date()).getTime() - this._startTick;
//     ms   =                 ms     -       ms
```

So to get to `"0.1"`/etc from *milliseconds* I'm assuming you are doing

```
(Math.floor(ms / 100) / 10).toString();
```

Why not just keep everything in `ms/100` so you can use integers?

```
var acc = [];
acc[ 1] =  1;
acc[ 3] =  2;
acc[ 6] =  4;
acc[ 9] =  8;
acc[20] = 16;
acc[50] = 32;
```

Then you can create a "nearest" lookup function like this

```
function find(x) {
    var i = 0;
    x = x | 0; // The | 0 will cause a cast to int
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    if (acc[x] !== undefined) return acc[x];
    if (x > acc.length) return acc[acc.length - 1];
    while (++i < acc.length) {
        if (acc[x - i] !== undefined) return acc[x - i];
        if (acc[x + i] !== undefined) return acc[x + i];
    }
}
find(this._delay / 100);
```

Now examples are

```
find(30);    // 16
find(100.5); // 32
find(0);     //  1
```

Comment: You're perfeclty right, thank you for your suggestion, I'll modify my code with this idea, but unfortunately this does not answer to my question (my keys problem).

Comment: And there's still one problem: if `(this._delay / 100) | 0` give an index out of range, I'd like it to give the highest possible value (`acc[4]`). How would you do?

Comment: @OlivierPons also, if you're expecting huge swathes of _undefined_ vs few defined, you might consider a lookup function closer to those described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-nearest-number-out-of-array

Comment: You can also fill up all elements of `acc` with the appropriate values (e.g. `acc[2] = 1` and get rid of the awkward checks in the while loop.